# How to get relative position of a draggable item when dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
    $(function() {
    // Make images draggable.
    $(".item").draggable({

    // Find position where image is dropped.
    stop: function(event, ui) {

        // Show dropped position.
        var Stoppos = $(this).position();
        $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
    }

    });
});
```

This will get the position of the item when I drop it, but it is relative to the browser window, not the div they are within.  How can I get their relative position?

edit-> Here is the html/css:

```
<style type="text/css">

.container {
    margin-top: 50px;
    cursor:move;
}
#screen {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    clear:both;
    border:1px solid black;
}                              

</style>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <div id="screen">
      <img id="productid_1" src="images/KeypadLinc OFF.jpg" class="item" alt="" title="" />
      <img id="productid_2" src="images/KeypadLinc ON.jpg" class="item" alt="" title="" />
    </div>

</div>


<div id="stop">Waiting image getting dropped...</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the parent div `position: relative`.

```
#screen {
    position: relative;
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter - What is wrong with my answer?  It works, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/z43fW/

Answer (score 0):

Set the containment attribute. For example:

```
$(".item").draggable( { containment: 'parent' } );
```

Keep in mind that the containment element (in this case `parent`) may not work with certain selectors.

From the documentation:

> Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or
>   region. Possible string values: 'parent', 'document', 'window', [x1,
>   y1, x2, y2].

See the [jQuery UI Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment) for more information.

Comment: that is not working.  i am editing my question with the html if that helps

Comment: Taking a look now, I'll post back shortly.

Comment: As you've seen with gilly's comment, adding position: relative; to the containing element will solve your problem.